# ACCESS 2010: How to select values from two queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have two selection queries and i want to select values from both and have a new query.
I tried to join them but I don't get the information i want to.

The first query that I have is the one below:

```
 SELECT InWarehouse.expiry_date, 
      drugs.active_substance, 
      drugs.strength, 
      drugs.strength_type, 
      drugs.dosage_form, 
      drugs.minimum_quantity, 
      NZ(SUM(InWarehouse.quantity),0) AS quant
 FROM drugs 
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT drug_id, 
                        expiry_date, 
                        SUM(in_quant - out_quant) AS quantity 
                FROM warehouse GROUP BY drug_id, expiry_date)  
 AS InWarehouse ON 
      InWarehouse.drug_id = drugs.id
      GROUP BY InWarehouse.expiry_date, 
      drugs.active_substance, 
      drugs.strength, 
      drugs.strength_type, 
      drugs.dosage_form, 
      drugs.minimum_quantity;
```

And the second one is:

```
 SELECT InPharmacy.expiry_date, 
      drugs.active_substance, 
      drugs.strength, 
      drugs.strength_type, 
      drugs.dosage_form, 
      drugs.minimum_quantity,
      NZ(SUM(InPharmacy.quantity), 0) as quant
 FROM (drugs
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT drug_id, expiry_date, SUM(in_quant - out_quant) as quantity
            FROM pharmacy
            GROUP BY drug_id, expiry_date) as InPharmacy
 ON InPharmacy.drug_id = drugs.id)

 GROUP BY  InPharmacy.expiry_date, 
      drugs.active_substance, 
      drugs.strength, 
      drugs.strength_type, 
      drugs.dosage_form, 
      drugs.minimum_quantity;
```

I want to get the:

```
InWarehouse.expiry_date, 
drugs.active_substance, 
drugs.strength, 
drugs.strength_type, 
drugs.dosage_form, 
drugs.minimum_quantity,
InWarehouse.quantity + InPharmacy.quantity,
InPharmacy.expiry_date
GROUP BY InWarehouse.expiry_date = InPharmacy.expiry_date
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between the warehouse table, drugs table and pharmacy table?

Comment: @bendataclear Yes, pharmacy and warehouse tables have as a foreign key the drug_id value. drug.ID is the primary key for the drug table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the two queries as subquery of a main query :

```
SELECT InWarehouse.expiry_date, 
t1.active_substance, 
drugs.strength, 
drugs.strength_type, 
drugs.dosage_form, 
drugs.minimum_quantity,
InWarehouse.quantity + InPharmacy.quantity,
InPharmacy.expiry_date
FROM (SELECT InWarehouse.expiry_date, 
      drugs.active_substance, 
      drugs.strength, 
      drugs.strength_type, 
      drugs.dosage_form, 
      drugs.minimum_quantity, 
      NZ(SUM(InWarehouse.quantity),0) AS quant
 FROM drugs 
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT drug_id, 
                        expiry_date, 
                        SUM(in_quant - out_quant) AS quantity 
                FROM warehouse GROUP BY drug_id, expiry_date)  
 AS InWarehouse ON 
      InWarehouse.drug_id = drugs.id
      GROUP BY InWarehouse.expiry_date, 
      drugs.active_substance, 
      drugs.strength, 
      drugs.strength_type, 
      drugs.dosage_form, 
      drugs.minimum_quantity  
) t1
JOIN (  SELECT InPharmacy.expiry_date, 
      drugs.active_substance, 
      drugs.strength, 
      drugs.strength_type, 
      drugs.dosage_form, 
      drugs.minimum_quantity,
      NZ(SUM(InPharmacy.quantity), 0) as quant
 FROM (drugs
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT drug_id, expiry_date, SUM(in_quant - out_quant) as quantity
            FROM pharmacy
            GROUP BY drug_id, expiry_date) as InPharmacy
 ON InPharmacy.drug_id = drugs.id)

 GROUP BY  InPharmacy.expiry_date, 
      drugs.active_substance, 
      drugs.strength, 
      drugs.strength_type, 
      drugs.dosage_form, 
      drugs.minimum_quantity ) t2
 ON t1.active_substance = t2.active_substance
```

I have used the `active_substance` field as a key to join the two table, if not appropriate you can choose the more appropriate set of columns , however the technique is two put the two dinstinct query as subquery of a main one and JOIN them in the proper way ...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't execute this. I get a warning message "The specified field 'drugs.active_substance' could refer to more that one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

Comment: It's OK but but it asks me to give the InWarehouse.quantity and the InPharmacy.quantity values.